# For Cloud Bigtable, do we need minimum of 3 nodes running all the time?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

I am trying to understand the [pricing of Cloud Bigtable](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/pricing). As per the website, for production it is $0.65/hr per node (minimum 3 nodes) apart from storage and network pricing. **Does this mean that 3 nodes are running all the time?** If yes, this would mean my estimated minimum monthly cost of nodes is:

> $.65/hr * 3 * 24hr/day * 30days/month = $1404/month

Is this correct? I was under the impression that Cloud Bigtable is also serverless and hence charges would be based on usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All nodes in your Bigtable cluster are running even if they are not used (no requests coming).

From the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/pricing#nodes):

> Node charges are for provisioned resources, regardless of node usage. Charges apply even if your cluster is inactive.

Your estimation is right (Bigtable cluster charges only), you can check [other pricing examples in the docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/pricing#example-no-replication).

Answer (score 3):

They changed the minimum number of nodes per cluster from 3 to 1 a few weeks ago.

> Instances have one or more clusters, located in different zones. Each cluster has at least 1 node.

Source: https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/instances-clusters-nodes